# directx sdk on windows 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

This is my first post here and please apologize me for my very poor English.

Current state:
I have a project that is very advanced, until now i use the DirectX SDK from June 2010, and several other librarys (Assimp, FreeImage, Bullet etc....).

My development environment is Win7, with VS2010 professional (win sdk 7.1A).

My question is, must i rewrite my DirectX code (with win sdk 8) to support windows 8?

I have searched around the web, and the only post that i find was the blog from Chuck Walbourn "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx".

Thank you in advance
Behnam Karaj
(From Stuttgart - Good Old Germany)

Comment: First sentence from the blog: "The DirectX SDK is now part of the Windows 8.0 SDK."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use DirectX SDK and Windows SDK 7.1A. It will work in Windows 8. But you will can not use it's new features, and cannot make Windows Store Apps.

Also, if you want to migrate to Windows 8 SDK, you don't need change much in your code, just a headers and some functions names and parameters.

If you want make Windows Store Apps you need to to migrate to Windows 8 SDK and cut some things such as D3DCompiler.h, Effects framework etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your useful and detailed answer.